# Probability of tossing a fair coin until getting a Tail.

Tags: probability

Let, $\Omega = \{T, HT, HHT, HHT, ... ...\}$

How can I prove that $ P(\{T\}) = \frac{1}{2}$, $ P(\{HT\}) = \frac{1}{4}$, $ P(\{HHT\}) = \frac{1}{8}$, and, so on?

Comment: it follows from the fact the coin is fair maybe?

Comment: @Alex, yes it is........

Comment: Have you heard of [Conditional Probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability#As_an_axiom_of_probability) and what is often referred to as the multiplication principle of probability?

Comment: @JMoravitz, Yes. But, I can't prove myself.